# Vaadin grid - save/cancel when setEnableEditor= true

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I'm new to vaadin and I'm a bit confused with the `save` and `cancel` `button` when `setEditorEnabled = true`.

Do you need to provide additional codes in order to save the data or it automatically saves all the data to the database when you click on save?

If there are aditional codes, how do I add a listener to the save and cancel buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use buffered mode, the edited values are written to the source object when you press the Save button. If you use unbuffered mode, the edition is written instantly, so the Save and Cancel button becomes meaningless.
If you want to write the edited object back to a database, you will need to add that functionality manually. It is practical to use buffered mode in this case and add the database calling method to a method that is called when the save button is pressed.

Besides adding it to a `CommitHandler`'s `postCommit` method, like Daniel Dubec writes, you can also override the `saveEditor()` and `doCancelEditor()` methods of the `Grid`.

```
class MyGrid extends Grid {

    public MyGrid() {
        setEditorEnabled(true);
        setEditorBuffered(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEditor() throws CommitException {
        super.saveEditor();
        // You can persist your data here.
        Notification.show("Item " + getEditedItemId() + " was edited.");
    }

    // Be aware that doCancelEditor() is called whenever super.saveEditor() is called!
    @Override
    protected void doCancelEditor() {
        super.doCancelEditor();
        // editedItemId was already set to 'null'.
        Notification.show("Cancel button was pressed");
    }
}
```

What `super.saveEditor()` does is actually calling the `commit()` method on the `editorFieldGroup`. But this is only meaningful, if the editable grid is in buffered mode. [Read more on Field Buffering here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-fields.html#components.fields.buffering).
So what happens is, when you press the save button, and `super.saveEditor()` is called, then first the pre-commit event is fired, then the the changes in the editor field values are updated to the data source (that is the commit itself), then the post-commit event is fired. The `doCancelEditor()` method is called whenever the editor itself is closed, this is why it is called after a save too.

Answer (score 1):

Or use saveListener. I am not sure if this is the best way, but it works for me.

```
Grid<Bean> grid;
grid.getEditor().addSaveListener(new EditorSaveListener<Bean>() {
            @Override
            public void onEditorSave(EditorSaveEvent<Bean> event) {
                // You can persist your data here
                persistBean(event.getBean());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add CommitHandler for FieldGroup

```
    grid.setEditorEnabled(true);

    // register save listener
    grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler(new CommitHandler() {
        @Override
        public void preCommit(CommitEvent commitEvent) throws CommitException {
        }
        @Override
        public void postCommit(CommitEvent commitEvent) throws CommitException {
            // You can persist your data here
            Notification.show("Item " + grid.getEditedItemId() + " was edited.");
        }
    });
```